# Object Sensor on conveyor belt (want to record the data in EEPROM for testing)

Tags: arduino-uno, eeprom, hc-sr04

```
void setup () 
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
pinMode(LED_Blue_pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LED_White_pin, OUTPUT);

Serial.begin(9600);
digitalWrite(LED_Blue_pin, LOW);
digitalWrite(LED_White_pin, LOW);

void loop()
{
    long duration, cm;

    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

    cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);
    long distance = 70 - cm ;

    if (distance < 20) {
        Serial.println("NO ITEM");
        digitalWrite(LED_White_pin, HIGH);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(LED_White_pin, LOW);
    }

    if (distance > 20 && distance < 70) {
        digitalWrite(LED_Blue_pin, HIGH);
        Serial.print("Item : ");
        Serial.print(item++);
        Serial.println(" stk");
    } else {
        digitalWrite(LED_Blue_pin, LOW);
    }

    delay(1500);
}


long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
    return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

The code above is for the Ultrasonic Sensor HC-SR04. The sensor detects items that passes through and counts them along the way. The Blue Led indicates that the sensor detected an item while the White Led detects none. How can I store the data from HC-SR04 to EEPROM? The reason is, I just want to test it out before I sent the data from EEPROM to a database server. I'm still a novice at this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [EEPROM.write()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMWrite) function. There is a useful [tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/EEPROMWrite) on the Arduino site.

The sample code from that tutorial is shown below:

```
/*
 * EEPROM Write
 *
 * Stores values read from analog input 0 into the EEPROM.
 * These values will stay in the EEPROM when the board is
 * turned off and may be retrieved later by another sketch.
 */

#include <EEPROM.h>

/** the current address in the EEPROM (i.e. which byte we're going to write to next) **/
int addr = 0;

void setup() {
  /** Empty setup. **/
}

void loop() {
  /***
    Need to divide by 4 because analog inputs range from
    0 to 1023 and each byte of the EEPROM can only hold a
    value from 0 to 255.
  ***/

  int val = analogRead(0) / 4;

  /***
    Write the value to the appropriate byte of the EEPROM.
    these values will remain there when the board is
    turned off.
  ***/

  EEPROM.write(addr, val);

  /***
    Advance to the next address, when at the end restart at the beginning.

    Larger AVR processors have larger EEPROM sizes, E.g:
    - Arduno Duemilanove: 512b EEPROM storage.
    - Arduino Uno:        1kb EEPROM storage.
    - Arduino Mega:       4kb EEPROM storage.

    Rather than hard-coding the length, you should use the pre-provided length function.
    This will make your code portable to all AVR processors.
  ***/
  addr = addr + 1;
  if (addr == EEPROM.length()) {
    addr = 0;
  }

  /***
    As the EEPROM sizes are powers of two, wrapping (preventing overflow) of an
    EEPROM address is also doable by a bitwise and of the length - 1.

    ++addr &= EEPROM.length() - 1;
  ***/


  delay(100);
}
```